# Storyboard 'Designated entry point not set'

Tags: xcode, storyboard, launcher

I got this little problem in Xcode 12 when I try to launch my app. Is someone could help me ?
[The problem message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM17h.png)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an initial view controller.

1.- Select the Main.storyboard and your first view controller (Navigation Controller, login, etc.)

2.- Open Attributes inspector and click "Is Initial View Controller" in the View Controller section.

3.- You will see an indicator on the left of the VC.

[image]

Comment: yes thanks, but I did this too and it still doesn't work..

Comment: Really? This problem is for the initial view controller. Also, you can clean, build and run your project. It's weird that dont works on your project

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the first answer and add this line to your AppDelegate.

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

Make sure you have your project like this. This need to work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you rename your storyboard file without updating the main interface? This could be causing your problem.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the general settings section of your app(this can be navigated to through the file with the little blue blueprint Xcode logo at the top of your files list)
2. Go to general
3. Under "Deployment Info" select the dropdown menu from "Main Interface".
4. Select which storyboard you would like to load first after your load screen.
5. Run the app.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5x8m.png)

If this doesn't work you could try what Diego said again and if that doesn't work then you might have to just rebuild it in a new Xcode project(hopefully it doesn't come down to that). I hope this was helpful!